# How can I register a global error converter on retrofit 2 + rx-android?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, retrofit2

My server returns domain java objects when everything goes ok, but returns an ErrorResponse object when there is an error. (EDIT: server returns http code 40x, and a json body with error info)
How can I register a global error converter on retrofit 2 + rx-android to avoid doing the same thing on every single call?

Currently I'm doing it like this on every call:

```
MyApiRx.doSomething(params)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe(response -> responseHandler(),
             throwable -> {
               HttpException err = (HttpException) throwable;
               Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> ec = retrofit.responseConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[]{});
               ErrorResponse errorResponse =  ec.convert(err.response().errorBody());
             });
```

Maybe I should write a custom CallAdapterFactory that would handle this automatically, and would return an Observable with an onError(ErrorResponse err) instead of the stock onError(Throwable t)?

Any ideas on how to achive this?

Is it a good idea?

Comment: check out this gist https://gist.github.com/rahulgautam/25c72ffcac70dacb87bd and this github issue https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1102

Answer (score 1):

There are few interesting methods of the `Observable` you could use. Especially you should take a look at those two:

[`onErrorResumeNext(Func1<Throwable, Observable> resumeFunction)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorResumeNext(rx.functions.Func1))

[`doOnError(Action1<Throwable> onError)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnError(rx.functions.Action1))

And since I don't see (in your example) a need for another `Observable` to gain control over the stream, the latter one will probably be better for you.

What you could do is to create a class that would wrap the handler for your errors (e.g. like this):

```
public static class Response {
    private static final Action1<Throwable> ERROR_HANDLER = new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            HttpException err = (HttpException) throwable;
            Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> ec = retrofit.responseConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[]{});
            ErrorResponse errorResponse =  ec.convert(err.response().errorBody());
        }
    };

    public static Action1<Throwable> handleError() {
        return ERROR_HANDLER;
    }
}
```

And then call your api with:

```
MyApiRx.doSomething(params)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .doOnError(Response.handleError())
  .subscribe(response -> responseHandler());
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that out. There are 2 problems I see with this approach though: 1. The class/methods you suggest cannot be static since they require an instance of "retrofit". 2. I still have to .doOnError on each and every request.

Comment: As for the first problem  - it still can be static, it just needs to be initialized as soon as you get your `Retrofit` instance. If you're using some sort of a dependency injection framework (e.g. dagger) it will be especially easy. As for the latter issue: you will have to do something. If you don't like `doOnError` you should be able to use `compose` instead ([here's](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) a nice article from Dan Lew on that function if you need a reference).